# Java Jframe Not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I have a question. I created a new project with netbeans and have main.java and i created a jframe that i called GUI.java. Now when I hit F6, my GUI.java dosen't appear and it runs but nothing shows up cause my main is empty. But if i right click on GUI.java, it shows up the jframe.

How do I go about getting my Jframe working properly to show up when I hit F6?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Learn to write GUI code by hand. GUI builder abstraction will leak. It's [the Law](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to customize the `<default config>` combo box and choose your preferred `Main Class`. Alternatively, you can put your GUI in a `JPanel` and `add()` it to a manually created `JFrame`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561540).

Comment: Thank you, this worked very easily. "The easiest approach is to customize the <default config> combo box and choose your preferred Main Class"

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you instantiate the JFrame from your main class, you'll need to set this.setVisible(true) in the JFrame constructor