# Netbeans Project Types

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop-application

I'm building a Java application using NetBeans 7.0.  The app is intended for use on Windows, so I guess the tool I'm really making most use of is Java Swing (for the cool, nifty screen elements).

My question relates to NetBeans' process of creating the various project types.  The application I'm building is based on the "Java Desktop Application" template (?).  My problem is that there seems to be a nice load of bloat built into that, and I can't figure out how to remove most of it without blowing up the app.

As a test, I created a "Java Application"project, but this has the opposite problem -- there's absolutely nothing built into the code, and I can figure out how to add anything.  Specifically, a Java Desktop Application project created in NetBeans give me the ability to directly edit the screen layout like in Visual Studio.  However, a Java Application does not appear to have this capability, I have no idea how (or even if) this can be addressed.

If I could start with a no-frills Java application, and add some capability to edit its layout and control the function of the screen elements (i.e. make it a windows application, I think), that would be just about perfect.

Does anybody have a suggestion for a minimal, but functional NetBeans application start point??

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 2):

If you start with a plain Java Application then as you realize you start with a bare bones type application. To add a GUI you can add New>JFRame Form. It adds a class that extends JFrame and Netbeans will recognize that it should open it in the visual editor for you.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561480/netbeans-gui-editor-generating-its-own-incomprehensible-code/2561540#2561540).