# Java swing menu doesn't stay up

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, menu, xming

So I'm running netbeans 7.0-1 using Arch Linux.  I'm running xming for my x-server.

What's going on is, when I use netbeans' Desktop Applications, it starts with two menus: File and Help. Whenever I click the drop down menu, the drop down immediately disappears.

I'm not even sure where to start... it seems like a bug. Any ideas?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561480/netbeans-gui-editor-generating-its-own-incomprehensible-code/2561540#2561540).

Comment: @Andrew: "Any ideas?"  Toss away the IDE you obviously don't know how to use and develop non-GUI applications in a simple editor until such times as you feel confident to debug the problems of your GUI programs.

Comment: @Andrew:  Perhaps I should have prefaced those ideas with the comment that inspired them *"I'm not even sure where to start".*  Netbeans is a powerful & useful IDE in the hands of a seasoned developer that is capable of delving into the guts of the code when it misbehaves (which it will).  For a newbie developer who 'does not know where to start', an IDE will just slow you down.  BTW - what happened to your shift key in your reply to me?  Is lower case meant to indicate sarcasm, or just laziness?

Comment: BTW - For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as it turns out... I needed to set the enviroment variable AWT_TOOLKIT to "MToolkit"

That seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: +1. Wow, Where did that come from? Why this have to do with it?

Comment: @Rekin: Well I guess what Java is using to display Netbeans can use several ToolKits... However, the one that is working best for me is the MToolkit.  You tell java to use it by setting the AWT_TOOLKIT variable.