# how to add JPanel to auto generated netbeans JFrame?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have auto generated netbeans GUI (JFrame) and I'm trying to add an external JPanel (different class) to the JFrame but it failed.  What i'm supposed to do?

Note: JPanel is a web browser using DJ Native Swing.

Comment: i tried to add the external panel to the auto generated frame

Comment: This is obvious from your original post. Why not tell us the details? Have you gone through the Swing tutorials? They will show you how to do all this and more.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that you would add the JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane just as you would with a non-NetBeans GUI, but again we're sort of hamstrung until you can tell us what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: +1 There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561480/netbeans-gui-editor-generating-its-own-incomprehensible-code/2561540#2561540).