# Desktop GUI framework

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frameworks

I tried to create a new Swing GUI desktop application template using NetBean 7.0 and just found NetBean has a disclaimer:

"Note that JSR-296 (Swing Application Framework) is no longer developed and will not become part of the official Java Development Kit as was originally planned. You can still use the Swing Application Framework library as it is, but no further development is expected."

So does it mean swing will stay the same from now on and nothing new will be added? What will that impact the applications using Swing? Do I need to consider other GUI frameworks instead? What would be the best framework option for a scientific plotting and graphic heavy application?

Thanks.

Comment: Swing App Framework is a different thing to Java Swing. Java Swing is still there in Java SE, so go on and use it if you want.

Comment: See also [Swing GUI listeners without AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/).

Comment: in fact, it _is_ further developed, just not by snoracle. It's called BetterSwingApplicationFramework, hosted on kenai http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home

Comment: possible duplicate of [Netbeans GUI editor generating its own incomprehensible code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561480/netbeans-gui-editor-generating-its-own-incomprehensible-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is part of JAVA since 1.2 and it is part of the JAVA STANDARD. It is not going anywhere any time soon.

The JSR-296 (Swing Application Framework) was a framework to simplify and help developing in swing, which didnt go very far. Netbeans uses it internally. If using JAVA 7 then, like many other netbeans specific libraries, you need to ship it separately with you app, because it is not standard.

So, feel free to develop in swing. A pure swing app WILL WORK on any JAVA STANDARD on almost any platform for a long time to come. If you use the SAF, thats also OK, but that is not standard and its pretty much dead, so just remember to ship the jar with your app.

Hope that clarifies the situation.

Comment: great answer - we noticed over here [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422957/easy-databinding-for-java ] that DT never accepts answers, so I'm sharing the votes to those that deserved it :)