# Databinding methods in Java similar to WPF?

Tags: c#, java, .net

IS there a way or an IDE that enables easy data binding in java like in Visual Studio/Silverlight/WPF? What would be the best way to do data binding in Java? using Hibernate or something? Is building GUI in Swing and Java a lot more difficult compared to .Net alternatives? While the cross platform advantage of Java is also a big factor, programming things in silverlight/WPF seems to be alot quicker than Java too. What else should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Eclipse RCP, it has good databinding support and a complete GUI environment.