# Draw a JPane in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing, jframe

I have search on internet and found a lot of information about drawing in Java. But when I add new JFrame class in Netbeans then I cannot add a own JPane in the JFrame. Hopefully somebody can help me with this issue/question.

Drawing the JPane is possible when I make a new JFrame in a class, but I would like to use the design view in Netbeans. That is not possible when I make a new JFrame.

I look forward to receiving an answer.

Comment: `JPane`?  Or `JPanel`?  ...I've never heard of a `JPane`...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a JFrame instance yourself, and then tried to add a JPane(l) to it using NetBeans swing builder. This wont work. Try creating a new swing class using the swing builder and let netbeans make the Jframe.
Also, make sure you set a correct layout for your JFrame.

Also, like BenCole said, I think you mean a JPanel, not a JPane.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, create your own [top level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and add your designer panel to its content pane. Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513). In this way you can limit the use of the designer to a single panel, while you explore [other layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).