# Netbeans:  How do I add a valueChanged listener to a JTable from the "design" GUI builder?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, netbeans-7

I right clicked the JTable and inserted some code into "post listeners code" in an awful kludge.

I don't see an option to add

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
```

to "events" in the "design" view for the JTable.  I'm sure there's a way to add a valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) from design view, but how?

maybe it's a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8089)?

> Row selection change events are produced by ListSelectionModel of
>   JTable, not by JTable itself - so the event cannot be presented in
>   Component Inspector (as event of JTable). Handling this event must be
>   done manually, e.g. like:

```
jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
    new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
            customRowSelectionEventHandler(evt);
        }
    }
);
```

Although maybe there's a way to get the ListSelectionModel for a JTable outside of the "blue", "managed," code?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? There's not a question mark in your question. Also, as a side note, [condense your code a little](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/181088)

Comment: How to add a valueChanged listener to a JTable via the "design" view of Netbeans? I don't see that option in the GUI builder.

Comment: @Thufir: A designer source file can be compiled, but changing the design requires the corresponding `.form` file. Even then, it's a pain to reconstruct. Also, nothing _requires_ that you use the designer for _everything_, nor is `GroupLayout` mandatory. It's a power saw: use it to cut treads to length, not to carve chess pieces.

Comment: good point.  I like the "clicky" stuff for GUI building, but maybe I'll make a custom JPane for my JTables, and then add those to other JPane's with the designer...?

Comment: @Thufir: Exactly, you can add such panel(s) to your main layout, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513). Changing a panel's layout is a good way to learn about the less common ones.

Comment: Almost exactly re-asked this question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658767/262852).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own `ListSelectionListener` in the editable part of the source. You can add an instance of the listener to the selection model of the class variable `jTable1` in your table's `Post-init Code` property:

```
jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MyListener());
```

The listener itself might look like this:

```
private static class MyListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could extend `InputVerifier`.

It's not exactly what it was intended to do, but you could adapt it for your uses.

```
public class TableVerifier extends InputVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        assert input instanceof JTable : "I told you I wanted a table!";

        JTable inputTable = (JTable) input;
        int numberColumns = inputTable.getColumnCount();
        int numberRows = inputTable.getRowCount();

        for (int column = 0; column < numberColumns; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < numberRows; row++) {
                //DO YOUR STUFF
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```