# Using a method from .java class in a .form project

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdbc

I have successfully created a Java class that provides database connectivity and returns a connection object. I need to use this connection object to

1. Retrieve information from the database (which I already know how to do)
2. I need to use it in the action event source code behind the button control

Unfortunately, I am using NetBeans and some auto generated code to build the GUI, and my question is simple:

When you create a class, you need to instantiate it and then call the method. Where do I instantiate this class in my form? Do I do it in the main, since it is the entry point of all programs, or do I do it behind the code for the button. I am a novice so please understand.

When I created the project, I created a main class too, and then I added a form to it. I then created a different project which is a class lib and added that to my project. How do I link the two together?

Comment: not too much details, making hard to answer it. maybe try to post your code?

Comment: well..i created a class (.java) with one method. I need to call this method in a form. Where do i instantiate(bring this class to life through an object) so that i may utilize this method in the code behind a button controll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the NetBeans GUI editor is clouding the picture. You can tame it by limiting it's use to a single panel, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513). The default [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, so `f.add(new NewJPanel())` has the effect of adding a panel to the `CENTER`. You can add other panels, perhaps ones having different layouts, to other areas.

Addendum: Note also that the generated `ActionListener` typically calls a method having a signature such as this, where `xxx` is the name of the generated control:

```
private void xxxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {}
```

These methods are *inside* the class but *outside* the generated code fold, so they may be edited as required.