# Accessing Default jFrame netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to display an image in a jlabel, which is in the default jFrame created by Netbeans. I know how to display an image in a new Jframe, but I dont know how to acces the default Jframe since I cant customize the code and create a variable name for it. Any work arounds?

The application is supposed to display pictures from  a directory, so when u press next, next image, and if you press previous the previous image will be shown. What will be the best data structure to do this efficiently so that I can keep track of the index as well?

Comment: *"Any work arounds?"*  Learn how to use Netbeans or learn Java.  Not sure which applies here, an expert user of Netbeans & Java can easily create a frame with a label with icon that changes according to user selection.  There is no 'work around' to understanding both (if using Netbeans).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting the GUI designer manage your *frame*, let it manage the *content*, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Addendum: There's an example of flipping through images [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad).

Comment: Oops, I missed the second paragraph of the question; more above.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding displaying the images, you can number the images in the directory as 1,2,3...and so on. If you do this, you can use a simple counter variable (increment with the next button and decrement with the previous button ) to scan through the images. You can use this counter variable for your image name with the format.