# Setting BorderLayout of a component added from Netbeans design view

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I've setting up a simple gui that shows a JTable when pressing a JButton, and i have no problem with this. My problem is that when the JTable is loaded, it overlaps the button(s). I think I can manage this with BorderLayout, I have used it with the JTable, but I can't figured out how setting BorderLayout parameters for the buttons, as I added them with the NetBeans design view.

```
 JTable dataTable=new JTable(data,columns);
 this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(dataTable);
 this.add(pane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
 getContentPane().validate();
 getContentPane().repaint();
```

As I said the buttons are added automatically by the Netbeans design view. Feel free to suggest me other code improvements if you want, I'm learning.

This is how it is
[image]

And when I scroll the JTable the JButtons scrolls too...Like they are in the same JScroll pane as the JTable.

This is how i would like it to be.
[image]

With the JButtons and the JTextField that remain at the same distance from the JTable, also when I scroll it.

Comment: See the suggestions in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14910808/230513).

Comment: add an image of how you want the gui to be and how it is appearing while execution

Comment: I've edited my post :)