# setSize of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, preferredsize

I am working with my new project.Now i am having so much Jframe pages.But i cant resize the frames by setSize methode.Please any one can help me in coding

The following set of codes contains a login screen

```
/*
 * LoginScreen.java
 *
* Created on July 6, 2013, 11:52 AM
*/

package com.macfast.mbaplus.admin;

import com.macfast.mbaplus.domain.Users;
import com.macfast.mbaplus.support.Util;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author  My
 */
public class LoginScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form LoginScreen */

@Override
public void setSize(int width, int height) {
    super.setSize(1000, 300);
}
public LoginScreen() {
    initComponents();

    signInBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
            char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
            String password = new String(pword);
            if (uname == null || uname.equals("") || uname.equals(" ") || password == null || password.equals("") || password.equals(" ")) {

                Util.showErrorMessageDialog("Please fill all the fields");

            }else {
                authenticateLogin();
            }

        }
    });
}
public Boolean authenticateLogin() {

    Boolean authenticationSuccess = false;
 Users user = null;
            String uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
            char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
            String password = new String(pword);
            Util util = new Util();
            user = util.authenticate(uname, password);
            if (null != user) {
                authenticationSuccess = true;
                Util.showSuccessMessageDialog("Welcome "+uname);
                this.dispose();
                if (user.getIsAdmin()) {
                    new AdminHome().setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    new Sections().setVisible(true);
                }

            } else {
                 Util.showErrorMessageDialog("Invalid Login Credentials");
            }
           return authenticationSuccess; 
}
/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    usrNameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    pwordTxt = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    signInBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(macfast.MacfastApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(LoginScreen.class);
    setBackground(resourceMap.getColor("Form.background")); // NOI18N
    setForeground(resourceMap.getColor("Form.foreground")); // NOI18N
    setName("Form"); // NOI18N

    jLabel3.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel3.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel3.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setName("jLabel3"); // NOI18N

    jLabel4.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("jLabel4.font")); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel4.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel4.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setName("jLabel4"); // NOI18N

    jLabel5.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel5.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel5.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setName("jLabel5"); // NOI18N

    jLabel6.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("jLabel6.font")); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel6.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setName("jLabel6"); // NOI18N

    jLabel7.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel7.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel7.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setName("jLabel7"); // NOI18N

    jPanel2.setName("jPanel2"); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel1.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); // NOI18N

    usrNameTxt.setText(resourceMap.getString("usrNameTxt.text")); // NOI18N
    usrNameTxt.setName("usrNameTxt"); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel2.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setName("jLabel2"); // NOI18N

    pwordTxt.setText(resourceMap.getString("pwordTxt.text")); // NOI18N
    pwordTxt.setName("pwordTxt"); // NOI18N

    signInBtn.setText(resourceMap.getString("signInBtn.text")); // NOI18N
    signInBtn.setName("signInBtn"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(signInBtn)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(pwordTxt)
                        .addComponent(usrNameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(usrNameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(pwordTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(signInBtn)
            .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 58, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 258, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(381, 381, 381))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39))))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LoginScreen().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField pwordTxt;
private javax.swing.JButton signInBtn;
private javax.swing.JTextField usrNameTxt;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

I am using the following code to setsize my jframe(check my updated codes start portion)>but its does not work.

```
@Override
public void setSize(int width, int height) {
    super.setSize(1000, 300);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify your question more precise? And show only the relevant code.

Comment: I'm not your down-voter, but I advise you to first learn to create your Swing GUI by hand before using NetBeans' code generator. This and frequent study of the Swing tutorials will force you to understand the rudiments of the Swing library. I also agree with @Patrick, that you should clarify your question so that we'll be better able to understand it and help you.

Comment: @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        super.setSize(1000, 300);
    }

Comment: Here is my code problem.i am trying to setsize for my frame using
    @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        super.setSize(1000, 300);}

but it does not work properly.

Comment: Don't let the GUI designer dictate you design; consider this [alternate approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `setSize()` anywhere. You're overriding it (which you shouldn't do), but you're not calling it.

Comment: Can i set by using     public Sections() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(1000, 300);
    }

?

Comment: Thanks bro...its works....I am very much tied.thats why i am asking this type of qstns...sorry for that

Comment: What happens when you try it? Isn't it the LoginFrame that you want to size? If so, why call it in the Sections constructor and not in the LoginFrame constructor?

Answer (score 4):

The best solution here is probably *not* to call `setSize(..)` at any point, but instead to call `pack()`.  That will ensure the GUI is the minimum size it needs to be in order to display the components within it.