# GUI tool issues with older java project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, windowbuilder

I've been given an old java project created by an ex-employee to improve, but I'm having issues with trying to get a GUI tool working with the existing forms/java files in the project.

I've installed WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse 4.3, but I can't bring up a design view for the main form window. Otherwise it does work if I add a new blank JFrame.

I also created the same project in Netbeans 7.3, but when I try bring up the design view, I'm given an error saying support for swing has been discontinued.

Does anyone know what I'm missing or what I could do?

If it helps anything, it was originally created with an earlier version of Netbeans, though I'd like to avoid using it if I can (partly because I don't know which version).

Comment: *"given an error saying support for swing has been discontinued."*  I very much doubt that is the exact message.  It probably has something to do with the Swing application framework, which, though based on Swing, is not Swing.  Don't paraphrase these messages, quote them word for word.  Oh, and I doubt either IDE will allow you to use the GUI designer.  That is only possible if the other developer used it.

Comment: The full error message was "NetBeans support of Swing has been discontinued. Please, use NetBeans 7.0 if you want to use this framework"

I just wanted to know if there was a more up-to-date GUI tool that was compatible with this project. I've made do by reverting to Netbeans 7.0.1 so far, I just would've preferred a more current tool for updating and designing the layout.

Comment: Oracle is putting effort into Java FX.  I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what I'm missing or what I could do?

Learn how to write a Swing GUI.  For that, see [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Could be [tag:jsr296], mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).