# Netbeans Swing UI designer - what does the hazard icon mean?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm working in the Design view of a Swing application and occassionally I see a small hazard warning symbol appear in the top corner of a component.

I assumed this was something to do with visibility overlap or similar but having adjusted things I can't match a guess against anything credible. Unfortunately it doesn't have a tool-tip and does not react to any mouse clicks.

Any ideas? Google does not seem to suggest anything either.

Answer (score 2):

The NetBeans help topic, *Java File and Object Node Icons*, may help identify the icon in question. Tool tips on each icon indicate the relevant name. The one labeled *error badge*, for example, means "The file cannot be parsed."

Comment: Can you post a [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)?

Comment: Yep here it is cropped - the icon is dead centre in the image. http://imagebin.org/269962

Comment: Similar to [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic51156.html). I haven't seen it in a long time; I _think_ it was from a size problem with _absolute layout_.

Comment: I am having these little symbols in a really complicated form, and I'm having trouble getting other components to align with the components that have the symbol, so I'm assuming that it has something to do with the layout (though I can't imagine what).

Comment: I try to minimize the risk using the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Answer (score 2):

It's a "free design" layout warning -- you put new component to panel/container without layout manager and need manually drag and resize it (e.g. attach it to container borders).