# How to split JFrame class?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am using netbeans to auto generate a JFrame.
I have many panels within the frame.
Is there a method for splitting the frame class into smaller classes in netbeans?
One class for each panel?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not a way to do this. This was one of the main reasons I create GUI only coding nowadays.

Comment: You may be able to use the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Comment: You can create a new `JPanel` form.  Copy all the components on one of the frames panels and paste onto the new `JPanel` form...

Comment: The answer to this seems to come down to whether you can actually program Java GUIs, as opposed to being your IDE's slave ('auto generate')..