# Automatic updating of custom graphical components in Netbeans graphical designer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, custom-controls

I am designing some custom graphical components using Netbeans 7.4.  I am making some smaller components that combine to make larger custom components.  However, when I change one of the bottom-level components, the changes do not propagate up to other elements.

Is there any way to insert a custom component so that changes to it's base percolate to all the instances?  Somewhat new to fiddling with Swing, so my apologies if this is a trivial thing.

I have already added them to a custom palette hoping that would do something, but alas to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetBeans GUI designer doesn't support this directly, but you can instantiate your own custom components as often as desired. The key is designing for reuse. I try to follow the Swing [*separable model architecture*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#separable), even if there's no need for a custom look & feel.

Edit: I added two instances of `NewJPanel` to `Main` like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/261156). When I changed the label's text in the designer, it changed in both panels at runtime.

```
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
f.add(new NewJPanel());
f.add(new NewJPanel());
```

Comment: So to be bluntly clear, in a situation where you design an element and use it in multiple places, but then change it, you simply have to delete and re-add the component in all the places it was used?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd have to delete anything. You can reuse a panel like they show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/261156). Any changes to the properties, including  code properties, get regenerated for each instance when you build the project.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I am referring to graphical elements.  Not code changes, code changes do propagate.  But if I move a button around on the original, it doesn't seem to update the location of the button in places where I use that object

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the problem. I added the example I tried.

Comment: I'm talking about the layout, spacing of elements for example.  If you have a panel that has a label in it, and you move the label, it does not percolate to all the places that panel is used.  You need to delete it and re-add the panel.

Comment: Right, if you paste a copy in the designer, but not if you instantiate the class and add it to a container.

Comment: Agreed.  But the physical graphical layout necessitates copying and pasting, that is the extra step I was curious if I could avoid.  It's slightly annoying if you fix auto-spacing shenanigans only to make a subtle tweak and have to re-adjust the spacing all over again