# Editing nested JDialog in Netbeans' Design mode

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nested-forms, jdialog

Say I have the following code:

```
public class MainDialog extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    static class SubDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog
    {

    }
}
```

If I open 'MainDialog.java' in design mode, I can only edit the GUI of the MainDialog class. Is there anyway to edit the SubDialog class in design mode?

Thanks

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware...

Comment: Are you sure? That is very inconvenient. How do developers work around this if they need access to private members in the outer class?

Comment: To even be "close" to been acceptable, the inner dialog would need to be `public` and `static` as Netbeans needs a way to create an instance of the dialog

Comment: They don't. They create separate, single based class based forms which are then configurable in some way, passing references of what they need backwards and forwards between them. Personally, I tend to hand code most my UIs and only rely on the form editor when time a is pressure or the layout is especially complex

Comment: Amen to that posted by @MadProgrammer programmer above. Your original plan does not lead to much re-usable or enhanceable code.

Comment: How did you even get that JDialog class defined like that in the frame class?

Comment: I typed it myself. The idea was to create a "Settings" dialog that could change private variables in the outer-class. However, given the feedback from @MadProgrammer, I guess the way I should do this is by passing the different 'settings' (or possibly the outer-class itself) to the stand-alone form and retrieving new values once the dialog is closed.

Comment: MadProgrammer is correct, separate classes are the way to go. But just so you know, Whatever code you type, don't expect it to be editable by the editor. Bu you _could_ drag and drop a dialog to the frame. Then go to the navigator window and you will see the dialog. You can double click it and it will show in the design view. Make sure you hand code to `pack() and `setVisible()` to it when you want to show it. But like I said, MadProgrammer gave you the more appropriate solution

Comment: Thanks for the tip @peeskillet. I tried that too but I still couldn't make it an inner-class dialog.

Comment: @MadProgrammer if you want to re-iterate what you said as an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To even be "close" to been acceptable, the inner dialog would need to be `public` and `static` as Netbeans needs a way to create an instance of the dialog.

Most developers will create separate, single based class, based forms which are then configurable in some way (via setters and getters), passing references of what they need backwards and forwards between them.

Personally, I tend to hand code most my UIs and only rely on the form editor when time a is pressure or the layout is especially complex

Comment: An example of this approach is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).