# Is Netbeans 8's GUI builder missing properties?

Tags: swing, user-interface, netbeans, gui-builder

My netbeans guy builder seems to be missing an option to change border style of jpanel. Videos and images of tutorials show a properties table that is a little different than mine.

EDIT:

So I created a new JPanel from File > new File. Et voila, the properties just popped up out of nowhere and also in the JFrame now.

[image: my netbeans]

[image: sample on the net]

Answer (score 5):

A [`java.awt.Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) is not a Swing component. You may be looking for [`javax.swing.JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), which includes "support for borders." For example, the cyan tinted `JPanel`, named `buttonPanel` in the illustration below, has a `TitledBorder`.

[image]

Comment: I'd swear the option wasn't there, but that was a pretty big (screenshot) mistake on my side. Thank you for your information, I didn't know the difference before.

Comment: @Josephus87: Glad you got it sorted; I try to limit the GUI-builder dependence using the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).