# Netbeans : Affect custom class in GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I have a very big Frame made with Netbeans GUI Builder. And of course, made by default all inside one file, called JFrameTest.java.

Now I want to modularise my code. I have a JFrame containing a JTabbedPane and inside a lot of JPanel.

What I want is to have for each JPanel inside the JTabbedPane a specific java file, with inside actions, subviews, etc ...

It is too late now ?
I means, all my Panel have subviews like JTable, Button, etc .. and are inside the JFrameTest file.
There is not a way to say : Move the Panel and its subviews inside this CustomJPanel class, etc.. ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to copy/paste a GUI view with Matisse.  You'll just have to make the individual JPanels by hand.

Comment: Use the approach illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).