# Java Webstart Dist Folder Empty

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start, jsr296

I compile my code without Webstart and the .jar file is properly created along with the lib folder in the dist folder.
When I try to compile my code with Webstart selected (signed or unsigned) the dist folder is empty.

Using Netbeans 8.0.2, JDK 1.7.  This application was originally created in 2012 and uses Swing Application Framework.

Please note the code compiles without Webstart.
Why won't it compile with Webstart?  Needing to fix quickly, not rewrite a whole bunch of stuff for no reason.

Output from Clean & Build:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\username\\NetBeansProjects\\selectionsoftware -
Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-clean.properties
Duplicated project name in import. Project jnlp-impl defined first in C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml and again in C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml
MyProject.init:
MyProject.deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-clean.properties
MYPKG1Utilities.init:
MYPKG1Utilities.deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-clean.properties
RefpropLibrary.init:
RefpropLibrary.deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build
RefpropLibrary.clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build
MYPKG1Utilities.clean:
RefpropLibrary.init:
RefpropLibrary.deps-clean:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\RefpropLibrary\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\RefpropLibrary\build
RefpropLibrary.clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build
MyProject.clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-jar.properties
Duplicated project name in import. Project jnlp-impl defined first in C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml and again in C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml
MyProject.init:
MyProject.deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-jar.properties
MYPKG1Utilities.init:
MYPKG1Utilities.deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-jar.properties
RefpropLibrary.init:
RefpropLibrary.deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build\classes
RefpropLibrary.compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\dist\RefpropLibrary.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\refproplibrary\dist\RefpropLibrary.jar"
RefpropLibrary.jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 29 source files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
MYPKG1Utilities.compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\dist
Copy libraries to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\dist\MYPKG1Utilities.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\mypkg1utilities\dist\MYPKG1Utilities.jar"
MYPKG1Utilities.jar:
RefpropLibrary.init:
RefpropLibrary.deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\built-jar.properties
RefpropLibrary.compile:
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\RefpropLibrary\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\RefpropLibrary\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\RefpropLibrary\dist\RefpropLibrary.jar"
RefpropLibrary.jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 84 source files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\classes
Copying 20 files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\classes
MyProject.compile:
Updating property file: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\src\com\mypkg\mypkg1\engine\main\resources\version.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\classes\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build\classes\META-INF
Copy libraries to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\dist\MyProject.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -jar "C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\dist\MyProject.jar"
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\build
MyProject.jnlp:
MyProject.jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\classes
C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\src\com\mypkg\mypkg1\selectionsoftware\EconomizerGUIView.java:162: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setModel(ComboBoxModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
        compressorTypesComboBox.setModel(compressorModels);
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
Note: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\src\com\mypkg\mypkg1\selectionsoftware\EconomizerGUIView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning
Copying 31 files to C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\username\NetBeansProjects\selectionsoftware\dist
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: "As of NetBeans 7.1, the Swing Application Framework module is no longer included in the NetBeans IDE."—[*SAFSupport*](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SAFSupport).

Comment: But the code compiles without Webstart.  Also, I have the libraries for the Swing Application Framework.  I know that it's not included in Netbeans as such, but the libraries still work.

Comment: Can you maintain the `.jnlp` manually?

Comment: @trashgod I can maintain the jnlp-impl.xml, but the .jnlp was never created, the entire dist folder is empty.  Nothing was created.  Or do you mean the master-application.jnlp.  I can maintain that.

Comment: Since it's no longer supported, I don't see another choice.

Comment: I've spent the past hour removing all of the Application Framework and still no change.  The dist folder is still empty.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched [tag:jar296] since [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Comment: I decided to do what I had read in other posts.  Start over!  I ended up recreating the entire application from scratch.  I was able to copy and paste some code, but the UI itself was all new.  Better luck to the next guy.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), perhaps giving hope to the next guy.