# Netbeans customize add method Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to customize the default add method used inside autogenerated initComponentes() function and use my own version. Specifically, I would like to add a boolean parameter to the method to perform or not perform certain operations like:
`public void add(Component comp, Object constraints, boolean skip)`
and use it. I tried to modify default code with Customize Code in Netbeans but the add method is not customizable. How I can do it with Netbeans (without modify autogenerated code outside)?

Than you in advance!

Comment: A better solution is to NOT use the IDE to generate your code, then you are in full control of the structure of your code. Now you are spending time learning how to use the IDE instead of learning Java/Swing. If you ever switch to a different IDE the code will not be maintainable. You can still use the IDE to help structure your classes and compile, test and debug.

Comment: Also consider the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).