# Why won't the JLabels or JButtons show up when running the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have been playing around with numerous solutions but none of them seems to work. in the constructor, there is a default `initComponents()` which I can not change. So I created a second method called `myComponents()`. The class I am using extends `JFrame` so I do not need to create another frame in any initializer. I created a `JPanel` with a vertical `Boxlayout`, 2 labels, 1 text field, and 1 button. I added the panel to the frame then I added all the components to the panel then packed everything.

I am unsure as to why nothing shows up besides the frame when it is run.

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author gpbli
 */
public class MAINFRAME extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MAINFRAME
     */
    //MAINFRAME frame = new MAINFRAME();
    JPanel homescreen = new JPanel();

    JLabel numOfIngredLabel = new JLabel();
    JTextField numOfIngred = new JTextField();
    JButton okButton = new JButton();
    JLabel logo = new JLabel();

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("logo_resized.png");
    public MAINFRAME() {
        initComponents();
        myComponents();
    }
    public void myComponents(){
        BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(homescreen,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        homescreen.setLayout(box);
    
    numOfIngredLabel.setText("How many Ingredients");
    numOfIngred.setText("");
    okButton.setText("OK");
    logo.setText(" ");
    logo.setIcon(img);
    
    add(homescreen);
    homescreen.add(logo);
    homescreen.add(numOfIngredLabel);
    homescreen.add(numOfIngred);
    homescreen.add(okButton);
    
    numOfIngredLabel.setVisible(true);
    numOfIngred.setVisible(true);
    okButton.setVisible(true);
    logo.setVisible(true);
    
    pack();
    revalidate();
    
    
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MAINFRAME.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MAINFRAME.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MAINFRAME.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MAINFRAME.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MAINFRAME().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The appearance of `initComponents()` suggests the IDE is expecting the programmer to use the GUI builder, while the `myComponents()` is the programmer taking control of the GUI construction to code it by hand. Use one or the other. I'd always use the latter, which does not require the `JFrame` to be extended. In fact, creating the main view of the GUI in a `JPanel` and adding that single component to a `JFrame` is the way we would typically recommend.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you! I am new to posting on stacked overflow how do I mark your response as helpful?

Comment: I'll defer to @AndrewThompson to post an answer; in the interim, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) illustrates the approach. If he demurs, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of `initComponents()` suggests the IDE is expecting the programmer to use the GUI builder, while the `myComponents()` is the programmer taking control of the GUI construction to code it by hand.

Use one or the other. I'd always use the latter, which does not require the `JFrame` to be extended. In fact, creating the main view of the GUI in a `JPanel` and adding that single component to a `JFrame` is the way we would typically recommend.

**Note:** See also the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/418556) to: [Netbeans GUI editor generating its own incomprehensible code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2561480/418556)